# SQL getting the date stamp for the next occurrence of a given day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_clubs c
  LEFT JOIN tbh_club_classes cc
    ON c.clubID = cc.clubID
  LEFT JOIN tbl_classes cl
    ON cl.classID = cc.classID
```

which returns data like so

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [clubID] => 
        [clubName] => Club 1
        [clubLocation] => Clyme Hall
        [clubPostcode] => 
        [classID] => 2
        [classType] => Kickboxing
        [classStart] => 17:00
        [classEnd] => 19:00
        [classNight] => Monday
        [classAudience] => Mixed
        [classCost] => 5.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [clubID] => 1
        [clubName] => club 2
        [clubLocation] => Sports Hall
        [clubPostcode] => 
        [classID] => 3
        [classType] => Karate / Judo
        [classStart] => 19:30:00
        [classEnd] => 21:00:00
        [classNight] => Friday
        [classAudience] => Mixed
        [classCost] => 5.00
    )
)
```

I want the classNight to return the weekday,day of the month, and the month on the next occurrence of the day stored in classNight so that I get something like this from my query.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [clubID] => 
        [clubName] => Club 1
        [clubLocation] => Clyme Hall
        [clubPostcode] => 
        [classID] => 2
        [classType] => Kickboxing
        [classStart] => 17:00
        [classEnd] => 19:00
        [classNight] => **Mon 26th Oct**
        [classAudience] => Mixed
        [classCost] => 5.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [clubID] => 1
        [clubName] => club 2
        [clubLocation] => Sports Hall
        [clubPostcode] => 
        [classID] => 3
        [classType] => Karate / Judo
        [classStart] => 19:30:00
        [classEnd] => 21:00:00
        [classNight] => **Fri 21st Oct**
        [classAudience] => Mixed
        [classCost] => 5.00
    )
)
```

I want to amend my query to get the desired results above. So what is happening is the classNight field which is a varcar format holds the day of the week the class is on and I want it to return the day of the week, day of the month, and month of the next day stored in the classNight.

I have done it using php with this code

```
$day = $row['classNight'];//ie Monday, Tuesday etc
$today = strtotime('today 00:00:00');
$date = strtotime($day."+1",$today);
$date1 = date("D d M",$date);
```

but I need to figure out how to do this within the SQL query.

### Edit

Maybe instead of the query returning the day of the month/day of the week and month have it just return the datestamp of the next instance of the day stored in the classNight field and then I can use php to display it in a format I need, that would be easier for everyone :)

I have found this code but can't get it to work

```
SELECT * (NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE,`classNight`) "NEXT DAY") AS dates
 FROM tbl_classes;
```

I am not sure this would give me the timestamp but is supposed to give me the day/month/year; can anyone see what's wrong with the above and how I can incorporate it into my query?

Comment: "can this be achieved within the query itself?" yep sure can.  Sorry don't mean to be sarcastic but you can do it in PHP or in MYSQL but you should include some additional example data and desired result.  Because it is unclear if you need to handle occurrence only be once per week, or that and once per month, biweekly, twice per week, and...etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Hi Matt, i have updated my question to hopefully make it easier to understand. i just need the day of the week, day of the month, and the month data of the next instance of the classNight day. So if classNight field is Monday and todays day is Thursday 29th September, i want the sql to get the upcoming mondays info (mon 3rd oct). Hope that helps

Comment: So what would happen during summer/winter stops? these things normally don't actually happen every week of the year. You'd probably be best off storing actual dates with the classes (though not with the classes enough to be in the same table) and select the nearest future date with each class.

Comment: believe it or not we carry on every week regardless just because people know where they are then. i get your point tho. i'm just wondering how i would keep the classes db updated if i were to have every class and date stored, because i would need to add new classes on a regular basis this way and knowing my memory i'd likely to forget to update it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of the date column in db? if it is in DATETIME or DATE you can make the following approach. Get today's date in the same format which table is storing, using PHP. Then use the same in the condition of the query like,

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_clubs c
  LEFT JOIN tbh_club_classes cc
    ON c.clubID = cc.clubID
  LEFT JOIN tbl_classes cl
    ON cl.classID = cc.classID
WHERE DATE(tablename.datecolumn) > $ date_variable
```

This will give you the classes from tomorrow onward. Remember one thing, in MySQL, we can only compare dates, but not the time. Again I don't know which format you're using to save the date, so it'll display only in same way in which it is stored. But after getting the result we can format it using PHP anyway.

Comment: Hi JTheDev, thanks for your reply, i don't have a date column within the database, i only store the day of the week the class is held on which is stored in the classNight field. i want the query to return the day of the week, day of the month, and month for the next occurnace of the day that is stored in the classNight field. I have updated my question to hopefully better it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the *next* day of a certain day of the week:

```
SELECT *,
       (curdate + interval (case when field(dow, 'Sunday', . . . , 'Sunday') >= dayofweek(curdate)
                                 then field(dow, 'Sunday', . . . , 'Sunday') - dayofweek(curdate)
                                 else 7 + field(dow, 'Sunday', . . . , 'Sunday') - dayofweek(curdate)
                            end) day
        ) as next_class_day
FROM tbl_clubs c LEFT JOIN
     tbh_club_classes cc
     ON c.clubID = cc.clubID LEFT JOIN
     tbl_classes cl
     ON cl.classID = cc.classID;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, unfortunately i can't get it to work as it keeps saying mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. I have updated my question to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: @BBLJ84 . . . The keyword for interval days is `day`; I had `days`.

Comment: I'm now getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '. . , 'Sunday') >= dayofweek(curate) then day' at line 2??? any ideas, thanks

Comment: @BBLJ84 . . . The `...` means fill in the rest of the days of the week.

Comment: ok i have it working, but its not producing the result i want, here is a row from the result. [clubID] => 1 [clubName] => Radley [clubLocation] =>
Sports Hall [classType] => Karate / Judo [startTime]
=> 19:30:00 [endTime] => 21:00:00 [classNight] => Monday [classPrice] =>
5.00 = [next_class] => 2016-10-09 now today is the 29th and as the classNight is Monday the next class is next monday which is 3rd Oct yet the script is returning the Fri 9th Oct? so its not returning the correct day nor the correct date? any ideas. Many Thanks